# Exercise: Refelxive Space and Hahn-Banach Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $(f_i)_{i\geq 1}\subset X'$. Prove that for any $x\in X$, $\sum_{i\geq 1}|f_i(x)|<\infty$ if and only if $\sum_{i\geq 1}|F(f_i)|<\infty$ and $F\in X''$.

I just finished $(\leftarrow)$, but I am finding the way to show  $(\rightarrow)$.

($\leftarrow$) Suppose $\forall F\in X'',\sum_{i\geq 1}|F(f_i)|<\infty$.
Consider $F_x$ defined by $F_x(f)=f(x)$ for $f\in X'$, $F_x$ is a bounded linear functional on $X'$. Then, $\sum_{i\geq 1}|f_i(x)|=\sum_{i\geq 1}|F_x(f_i)|<\infty.$

Comment: What do you mean by "there exists $\sum_{i\geq 1}|f_i(x)|<\infty$"?  Do you mean $\sum_{i\geq 1}|f_i(x)|<\infty$, or is there something that you're trying to show exists?

Comment: Yes, it should be just "$\sum_{i\geq 1} |f_i(x)|<\infty$".

Comment: Then what do we know about $F$?